# Logging best practices

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging, trace

I'd like to get stories on how people are handling tracing and logging in real applications. Here are some questions that might help to explain your answer.

**Frameworks**

What frameworks do you use?

- log4net
- System.Diagnostics.Trace
- System.Diagnostics.TraceSource
- Logging application block
- Other?

If you use tracing, do you make use of Trace.Correlation.StartLogicalOperation?

Do you write this code manually, or do you use some form of aspect oriented programming to do it? Care to share a code snippet?

Do you provide any form of granularity over trace sources? E.g., WPF TraceSources allow you to configure them at various levels:

- System.Windows - *settings for all of WPF*
- System.Windows.Animation - *override specifically for Animation.*

**Listeners**

What log outputs do you use?

- Text files
- XML files
- Event log
- Other?

If using files, do you use rolling logs or just a single file? How do you make the logs available for people to consume?

**Viewing**

What tools to you use for viewing the logs?

- Notepad
- Tail
- Event viewer
- Systems Center Operations Manager/Microsoft Operations Manger
- WCF Service Trace Viewer
- Other?

If you are building an ASP.NET solution, do you also use ASP.NET Health Monitoring? Do you include trace output in the health monitor events? What about Trace.axd?

What about custom performance counters?

Comment: It would be helpful if people closing questions like this with 300 upvotes could suggest either a wiki format or posting on programmers.stackexchange, or else Quora if this type of question isn't welcome. Obviously the question is actually very constructive, it's just not fitting the criteria StackOverflow wants. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/best-practices-for-logging-and-tracing-in-net has 24 upvotes. Perhaps StackOverflow is missing something?

Comment: If this question violates the Q&A format then there IS SOMETHING WRONG with the Q&A Format and not with this question. Sometimes the decision whether a question should get closed should be a function of the answers provided, some open-ended questions invite debate, but others invite users to provide valuable content, such as this one!

Comment: This question - particularly the top answer - would probably make an excellent foundation for a blog post if someone wanted to use it as such... As an objective question, it doesn't really fit - it's structured explicitly as a straw poll - but there is some good information below, hence the lock.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

---

**Update:** For extensions to System.Diagnostics, providing some of the missing listeners you might want, see Essential.Diagnostics on CodePlex (http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/)

---

***Frameworks***

### Q: What frameworks do you use?

**A: System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, built in to .NET 2.0.**

It provides powerful, flexible, high performance logging for applications, however many developers are not aware of its capabilities and do not make full use of them.

There are some areas where additional functionality is useful, or sometimes the functionality exists but is not well documented, however this does not mean that the entire logging framework (which is designed to be extensible) should be thrown away and completely replaced like some popular alternatives (NLog, log4net, Common.Logging, and even EntLib Logging).

Rather than change the way you add logging statements to your application and re-inventing the wheel, just extended the System.Diagnostics framework in the few places you need it.

It seems to me the other frameworks, even EntLib, simply suffer from Not Invented Here Syndrome, and I think they have wasted time re-inventing the basics that already work perfectly well in System.Diagnostics (such as how you write log statements), rather than filling in the few gaps that exist. In short, don't use them -- they aren't needed.

**Features you may not have known:**

- Using the TraceEvent overloads that take a format string and args can help performance as parameters are kept as separate references until after Filter.ShouldTrace() has succeeded. This means no expensive calls to ToString() on parameter values until after the system has confirmed message will actually be logged.
- The Trace.CorrelationManager allows you to correlate log statements about the same logical operation (see below).
- VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener is good for writing to log files and supports file rotation. Although in the VisualBasic namespace, it can be just as easily used in a C# (or other language) project simply by including the DLL.
- When using EventLogTraceListener if you call TraceEvent with multiple arguments and with empty or null format string, then the args are passed directly to the EventLog.WriteEntry() if you are using localized message resources.
- The Service Trace Viewer tool (from WCF) is useful for viewing graphs of activity correlated log files (even if you aren't using WCF). This can really help debug complex issues where multiple threads/activites are involved.
- Avoid overhead by clearing all listeners (or removing Default); otherwise Default will pass everything to the trace system (and incur all those ToString() overheads).

**Areas you might want to look at extending (if needed):**

- Database trace listener
- Colored console trace listener
- MSMQ / Email / WMI trace listeners (if needed)
- Implement a FileSystemWatcher to call Trace.Refresh for dynamic configuration changes

**Other Recommendations:**

Use structed event id's, and keep a reference list (e.g. document them in an enum).

Having unique event id's for each (significant) event in your system is very useful for correlating and finding specific issues. It is easy to track back to the specific code that logs/uses the event ids, and can make it easy to provide guidance for common errors, e.g. error 5178 means your database connection string is wrong, etc.

Event id's should follow some kind of structure (similar to the Theory of Reply Codes used in email and HTTP), which allows you to treat them by category without knowing specific codes.

e.g. The first digit can detail the general class: 1xxx can be used for 'Start' operations, 2xxx for normal behaviour, 3xxx for activity tracing, 4xxx for warnings, 5xxx for errors, 8xxx for 'Stop' operations, 9xxx for fatal errors, etc.

The second digit can detail the area, e.g. 21xx for database information (41xx for database warnings, 51xx for database errors), 22xx for calculation mode (42xx for calculation warnings, etc), 23xx for another module, etc.

Assigned, structured event id's also allow you use them in filters.

### Q: If you use tracing, do you make use of Trace.Correlation.StartLogicalOperation?

**A: Trace.CorrelationManager is very useful for correlating log statements in any sort of multi-threaded environment (which is pretty much anything these days).**

You need at least to set the ActivityId once for each logical operation in order to correlate.

Start/Stop and the LogicalOperationStack can then be used for simple stack-based context. For more complex contexts (e.g. asynchronous operations), using TraceTransfer to the new ActivityId (before changing it), allows correlation.

The Service Trace Viewer tool can be useful for viewing activity graphs (even if you aren't using WCF).

### Q: Do you write this code manually, or do you use some form of aspect oriented programming to do it? Care to share a code snippet?

**A: You may want to create a scope class, e.g. LogicalOperationScope, that (a) sets up the context when created and (b) resets the context when disposed.**

This allows you to write code such as the following to automatically wrap operations:

```
  using( LogicalOperationScope operation = new LogicalOperationScope("Operation") )
  {
    // .. do work here
  }
```

On creation the scope could first set ActivityId if needed, call StartLogicalOperation and then log a TraceEventType.Start message. On Dispose it could log a Stop message, and then call StopLogicalOperation.

### Q: Do you provide any form of granularity over trace sources? E.g., WPF TraceSources allow you to configure them at various levels.

**A: Yes, multiple Trace Sources are useful / important as systems get larger.**

Whilst you probably want to consistently log all Warning & above, or all Information & above messages, for any reasonably sized system the volume of Activity Tracing (Start, Stop, etc) and Verbose logging simply becomes too much.

Rather than having only one switch that turns it all either on or off, it is useful to be able to turn on this information for one section of your system at a time.

This way, you can locate significant problems from the usually logging (all warnings, errors, etc), and then "zoom in" on the sections you want and set them to Activity Tracing or even Debug levels.

The number of trace sources you need depends on your application, e.g. you may want one trace source per assembly or per major section of your application.

If you need even more fine tuned control, add individual boolean switches to turn on/off specific high volume tracing, e.g. raw message dumps. (Or a separate trace source could be used, similar to WCF/WPF).

You might also want to consider separate trace sources for Activity Tracing vs general (other) logging, as it can make it a bit easier to configure filters exactly how you want them.

Note that messages can still be correlated via ActivityId even if different sources are used, so use as many as you need.

---

### Listeners

**Q: What log outputs do you use?**

This can depend on what type of application you are writing, and what things are being logged. Usually different things go in different places (i.e. multiple outputs).

I generally classify outputs into three groups:

**(1) Events - Windows Event Log (and trace files)**

e.g. If writing a server/service, then best practice on Windows is to use the Windows Event Log (you don't have a UI to report to).

In this case all Fatal, Error, Warning and (service-level) Information events should go to the Windows Event Log. The Information level should be reserved for these type of high level events, the ones that you want to go in the event log, e.g. "Service Started", "Service Stopped", "Connected to Xyz", and maybe even "Schedule Initiated", "User Logged On", etc.

In some cases you may want to make writing to the event log a built-in part of your application and not via the trace system (i.e. write Event Log entries directly). This means it can't accidentally be turned off. (Note you still also want to note the same event in your trace system so you can correlate).

In contrast, a Windows GUI application would generally report these to the user (although they may also log to the Windows Event Log).

Events may also have related performance counters (e.g. number of errors/sec), and it can be important to co-ordinate any direct writing to the Event Log, performance counters, writing to the trace system and reporting to the user so they occur at the same time.

i.e. If a user sees an error message at a particular time, you should be able to find the same error message in the Windows Event Log, and then the same event with the same timestamp in the trace log (along with other trace details).

**(2) Activities - Application Log files or database table (and trace files)**

This is the regular activity that a system does, e.g. web page served, stock market trade lodged, order taken, calculation performed, etc.

Activity Tracing (start, stop, etc) is useful here (at the right granuality).

Also, it is very common to use a specific Application Log (sometimes called an Audit Log). Usually this is a database table or an application log file and contains structured data (i.e. a set of fields).

Things can get a bit blurred here depending on your application. A good example might be a web server which writes each request to a web log; similar examples might be a messaging system or calculation system where each operation is logged along with application-specific details.

A not so good example is stock market trades or a sales ordering system. In these systems you are probably already logging the activity as they have important business value, however the principal of correlating them to other actions is still important.

As well as custom application logs, activities also often have related peformance counters, e.g. number of transactions per second.

In generally you should co-ordinate logging of activities across different systems, i.e. write to your application log at the same time as you increase your performance counter and log to your trace system. If you do all at the same time (or straight after each other in the code), then debugging problems is easier (than if they all occur at diffent times/locations in the code).

**(3) Debug Trace - Text file, or maybe XML or database.**

This is information at Verbose level and lower (e.g. custom boolean switches to turn on/off raw data dumps). This provides the guts or details of what a system is doing at a sub-activity level.

This is the level you want to be able to turn on/off for individual sections of your application (hence the multiple sources). You don't want this stuff cluttering up the Windows Event Log. Sometimes a database is used, but more likely are rolling log files that are purged after a certain time.

A big difference between this information and an Application Log file is that it is unstructured. Whilst an Application Log may have fields for To, From, Amount, etc., Verbose debug traces may be whatever a programmer puts in, e.g. "checking values X={value}, Y=false", or random comments/markers like "Done it, trying again".

One important practice is to make sure things you put in application log files or the Windows Event Log also get logged to the trace system with the same details (e.g. timestamp). This allows you to then correlate the different logs when investigating.

If you are planning to use a particular log viewer because you have complex correlation, e.g. the Service Trace Viewer, then you need to use an appropriate format i.e. XML. Otherwise, a simple text file is usually good enough -- at the lower levels the information is largely unstructured, so you might find dumps of arrays, stack dumps, etc. Provided you can correlated back to more structured logs at higher levels, things should be okay.

**Q: If using files, do you use rolling logs or just a single file? How do you make the logs available for people to consume?**

A: For files, generally you want rolling log files from a manageability point of view (with System.Diagnostics simply use VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener).

Availability again depends on the system. If you are only talking about files then for a server/service, rolling files can just be accessed when necessary. (Windows Event Log or Database Application Logs would have their own access mechanisms).

If you don't have easy access to the file system, then debug tracing to a database may be easier. [i.e. implement a database TraceListener].

One interesting solution I saw for a Windows GUI application was that it logged very detailed tracing information to a "flight recorder" whilst running and then when you shut it down if it had no problems then it simply deleted the file.

If, however it crashed or encountered a problem then the file was not deleted. Either if it catches the error, or the next time it runs it will notice the file, and then it can take action, e.g. compress it (e.g. 7zip) and email it or otherwise make available.

Many systems these days incorporate automated reporting of failures to a central server (after checking with users, e.g. for privacy reasons).

---

### Viewing

**Q: What tools to you use for viewing the logs?**

A: If you have multiple logs for different reasons then you will use multiple viewers.

Notepad/vi/Notepad++ or any other text editor is the basic for plain text logs.

If you have complex operations, e.g. activities with transfers, then you would, obviously, use a specialized tool like the Service Trace Viewer. (But if you don't need it, then a text editor is easier).

As I generally log high level information to the Windows Event Log, then it provides a quick way to get an overview, in a structured manner (look for the pretty error/warning icons). You only need to start hunting through text files if there is not enough in the log, although at least the log gives you a starting point. (At this point, making sure your logs have co-ordinated entires becomes useful).

Generally the Windows Event Log also makes these significant events available to monitoring tools like MOM or OpenView.

**Others --**

If you log to a Database it can be easy to filter and sort informatio (e.g. zoom in on a particular activity id. (With text files you can use Grep/PowerShell or similar to filter on the partiular GUID you want)

MS Excel (or another spreadsheet program). This can be useful for analysing structured or semi-structured information if you can import it with the right delimiters so that different values go in different columns.

When running a service in debug/test I usually host it in a console application for simplicity I find a colored console logger useful (e.g. red for errors, yellow for warnings, etc). You need to implement a custom trace listener.

Note that the framework does not include a colored console logger or a database logger so, right now, you would need to write these if you need them (it's not too hard).

It really annoys me that several frameworks (log4net, EntLib, etc) have wasted time re-inventing the wheel and re-implemented basic logging, filtering, and logging to text files, the Windows Event Log, and XML files, each in their own different way (log statements are different in each); each has then implemented their own version of, for example, a database logger, when most of that already existed and all that was needed was a couple more trace listeners for System.Diagnostics. Talk about a big waste of duplicate effort.

**Q: If you are building an ASP.NET solution, do you also use ASP.NET Health Monitoring? Do you include trace output in the health monitor events? What about Trace.axd?**

These things can be turned on/off as needed. I find Trace.axd quite useful for debugging how a server responds to certain things, but it's not generally useful in a heavily used environment or for long term tracing.

**Q: What about custom performance counters?**

For a professional application, especially a server/service, I expect to see it fully instrumented with both Performance Monitor counters and logging to the Windows Event Log. These are the standard tools in Windows and should be used.

You need to make sure you include installers for the performance counters and event logs that you use; these should be created at installation time (when installing as administrator). When your application is running normally it should not need have administration privileges (and so won't be able to create missing logs).

This is a good reason to practice developing as a non-administrator (have a separate admin account for when you need to install services, etc). If writing to the Event Log, .NET will automatically create a missing log the first time you write to it; if you develop as a non-admin you will catch this early and avoid a nasty surprise when a customer installs your system and then can't use it because they aren't running as administrator.

Comment: FYI: I encountered an issue where the microsoft trace to a file crashes. If you have multiple processes (or threads) writing to the same file and they collide you get a file system exclusive access locking error on the log file.

Comment: @Jay this is a fault with the trace listener (you can write your own), not the tracing infrastructure

Comment: The System.Diagnostics infrastructure is thread-safe; the default behaviour is for the framework to lock, however you can override TraceListener.IsThreadSafe if you provide your own locking. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.isthreadsafe.aspx.

For multiple processes you would normally write to separate files, but note that the Service Trace Viewer can load multiple trace files (e.g. from multiple machines) and correlate them via ActivityId.

Comment: May be you can suggest how to use TraceEvent() to log exceptions?

Comment: Isn't one of the major draw-backs of `System.Diagnostics.Trace` that it's decorated with `[Conditional("TRACE")]` which makes it unusable in production environments, where you rarely have code compiled with the `TRACE` flag?

Comment: @Dmitriy To log an exception is easy: source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 5000, "Exception occurred: {0}", exception); (this will get a full stack trace, etc, don't use exception.Message as it usually doesn't have enough information).

Comment: @asbjornu The default Release build configuration in Visual Studio has TRACE defined (it is DEBUG that is turned off for Release builds); if building from the command line you do, however, need to turn it on.

Answer (score 40):

I have to join the chorus recommending log4net, in my case coming from a platform flexibility (desktop .Net/Compact Framework, 32/64-bit) point of view.

However, wrapping it in a private-label API is a **major anti-pattern**.  `log4net.ILogger` is the .Net counterpart of the [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) wrapper [API](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html) already, so coupling is already minimized for you, and since it is also an Apache library, that's usually not even a concern because you're not giving up any control: fork it if you must.

Most house wrapper libraries I've seen also commit one or more of a litany of faults:

42. **Using a global singleton logger** (or equivalently a static entry point) which loses the fine resolution of the recommended [logger-per-class pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#Are%20there%20any%20suggested%20ways%20for%20naming%20loggers?) for no other selectivity gain.
43. **Failing to expose the optional `Exception` argument**, leading to multiple problems:

    - It makes an exception logging policy even more difficult to maintain, so nothing  is done consistently with exceptions.
    - Even with a consistent policy, formatting the exception away into a string loses data prematurely.  I've written a custom `ILayout` decorator that performs detailed drill-down on an exception to determine the chain of events.
44. **Failing to expose the `IsLevelEnabled` properties**, which discards the ability to skip formatting code when areas or levels of logging are turned off.

Comment: I was tasked with refactoring a (horrible) in-house wrapper around log4j into something somewhat less horrible (it's still pretty bad, but that's a result of shoehorning the requirements I was given into log4j). I tried to eliminate the global static entry point, but was shot down. I really don't get the point. In our setup, log4j is so heavily extended and twisted that it's really just being used as an event dispatcher; we're only using it because someone asked "how can we use log4j for this?" Either use log4whatever straight up, or just write your own framework. The middle road is painful.

Comment: I disagree with your recommendation not to wrap log4net.  Wrapping it with a thin provider-model API allows users of your class libraries to plug their favorite logging framework.  YMMV of course, but describing it as a "major anti-pattern" is a bit dogmatic.  Also the fact that there exist wrapper libraries with "a litany of faults" isn't a good argument against a well-written wrapper.

Comment: Calling something an anti-pattern doesn't mean it's always 100% a bad idea -- just that it creates a tendency to paint yourself into a corner if you're not careful.  Also, ILog/LogManager is itself a well written wrapper mini-library in the image of commons-logging that's bundled in the log4net assembly, but there's no reason it can't be extracted and turned into a proper commons-logging for CLR.

Answer (score 18):

I don't often develop in asp.net, however when it comes to loggers I think a lot of best practices are universal. Here are some of my random thoughts on logging that I have learned over the years:

#### Frameworks

- Use a logger abstraction framework - like slf4j (or roll your own), so that you decouple the logger implementation from your API. I have seen a number of logger frameworks come and go and you are better off being able to adopt a new one without much hassle.
- Try to find a framework that supports a variety of output formats.
- Try to find a framework that supports plugins / custom filters.
- Use a framework that can be configured by external files, so that your customers / consumers can tweak the log output easily so that it can be read by commerical log management applications with ease.
- Be sure not to go overboard on custom logging levels, otherwise you may not be able to move to different logging frameworks.

#### Logger Output

- Try to avoid XML/RSS style logs for logging that could encounter catastrophic failures. This is important because if the power switch is shut off without your logger writing the closing `</xxx>` tag, your log is broken.
- Log threads. Otherwise, it can be very difficult to track the flow of your program.
- If you have to internationalize your logs, you may want to have a developer only log in English (or your language of choice).
- Sometimes having the option to insert logging statements into SQL queries can be a lifesaver in debugging situations. Such as:

```
    -- Invoking Class: com.foocorp.foopackage.FooClass:9021
    SELECT * FROM foo;
```

- You want class-level logging. You normally don't want static instances of loggers as well - it is not worth the micro-optimization.
- Marking and categorizing logged exceptions is sometimes useful because not all exceptions are created equal. So knowing a subset of important exceptions a head of time is helpful, if you have a log monitor that needs to send notifications upon critical states.
- Duplication filters will save your eyesight and hard disk. Do you really want to see the same logging statement repeated 10^10000000 times? Wouldn't it be better just to get a message like:
  `This is my logging statement - Repeated 100 times`

Also see [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112771/what-is-a-good-way-to-pass-useful-state-information-to-an-exception-in-java).

Comment: duplication filters are a great idea

Comment: i used to agree on the broken tag problem, but most good XML writers don't use full XML anyway (i.e., no root element) so they can log without loading the XML DOM. in the uncommon case a problem occurs from a partially written entry, you can manually fix it

Comment: I have been going back and forth on XML logging for years. Now, it seems excessive to me. If I needed a RSS feed of the status of an application, I think it is better implemented with a log monitoring utility.

Comment: I agree on RSS. I'm thinking more about visualization tools that allow you to better understand the entry. with text files you generally want to keep an entry to one line; but sometimes you want to include stack traces or serialized objects. that's where an XML log (as used by WCF) comes in handy

Comment: +1 for mentioning instrumentation of SQL queries. This is indeed very useful for correlation of database traces and application traces. I am doing it manually in my DAL, but I wonder what kind of tool support is there for this technique?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not qualified to comment on logging for .Net, since my bread and butter is Java, but we've had a migration in our logging over the last 8 years you may find a useful analogy to your question.

We started with a Singleton logger that was used by every thread within the JVM, and set the logging level for the entire process.  This resulted in huge logs if we had to debug even a very specific part of the system, so lesson number one is to segment your logging.

Our current incarnation of the logger allows multiple instances with one defined as the default.  We can instantiate any number of child loggers that have different logging levels, but the most useful facet of this architecture is the ability to create loggers for individual packages and classes by simply changing the logging properties.  Lesson number two is to create a flexible system that allows overriding its behavior without changing code.

We are using the Apache commons-logging library wrapped around Log4J.

Hope this helps!

*** Edit ***

After reading Jeffrey Hantin's post below, I realized that I should have noted what our internal logging wrapper has actually become.  It's now essentially a factory and is strictly used to get a working logger using the correct properties file (which for legacy reasons hasn't been moved to the default position).  Since you can specify the logging configuration file on command line now, I suspect it will become even leaner and if you're starting a new application, I'd definitely agree with his statement that you shouldn't even bother wrapping the logger.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do you create the child loggers manually in code (i.e., are they hard coded) or through some kind of automatic/implicit thing?

Comment: No ... if we add a logging configuration to the logging.properties files for a package or class, they will be logged per that configuration but any package or class not specifically configured will be logged at the default levels.

Answer (score 9):

We use Log4Net at work as the logging provider, with a singleton wrapper for the log instance (although the singleton is under review, questioning whether they are a good idea or not).

We chose it for the following reasons:

- Simple configuration/ reconfiguration on various environments
- Good number of pre-built appenders
- One of the CMS's we use already had it built in
- Nice number of log levels and configurations around them

*I should mention, this is speaking from an ASP.NET development point of view*

I can see some merits in using the Trace that is in the .NET framework but I'm not entirely sold on it, mainly because the components I work with don't really do any Trace calls. The only thing that I frequently use that does is `System.Net.Mail` from what I can tell.

So we have a library which wraps log4net and within our code we just need stuff like this:

```
Logger.Instance.Warn("Something to warn about");
Logger.Instance.Fatal("Something went bad!", new Exception());

try {
  var i = int.Parse("Hello World");
} catch(FormatException, ex) {
  Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
}
```

Within the methods we do a check to see if the logging level is enabled, so you don't have redundant calls to the log4net API (so if Debug isn't enabled, the debug statements are ignored), but when I get some time I'll be updating it to expose those so that you can do the checks yourself. This will prevent evaluations being undertaken when they shouldn't, eg:

```
Logger.Instance.Debug(string.Format("Something to debug at {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

This will become:

```
if(Logger.DebugEnabled) Logger.Instance.Debug(string.Format("Something to debug at {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

(Save a bit of execusion time)

By default we log at two locations:

1. File system of the website (in a non-served file extension)
2. Email sending for Error & Fatal

Files are done as rolling of each day or 10mb (IIRC). We don't use the EventLog as it can require higher security than we often want to give a site.

I find Notepad works just fine for reading logs.

Comment: Logging frameworks are one of few instances where the singleton isn't a misuse.

Comment: It can be if you want to provide a context around your logger. But it does help to deal with concurrency

Comment: I would definitely rip out the singleton. You can certainly have a single *instance* which gets passed around (preferably in the IOC/DI container). I would also try to move logging into an interceptor....

Comment: Not a fan of the single instance either.  I prefer to give each class a uniquely named logger so turning logging up or down on a per module basis is easy-peasy.

Answer (score 8):

**What frameworks do you use?**

We use a mix of the logging application block, and a custom logging helper that works around the .Net framework bits. The LAB is configured to output fairly extensive log files included seperate general trace files for service method entry/exit and specific error files for unexpected issues. The configuration includes date/time, thread, pId etc. for debug assistance as well as the full exception detail and stack (in the case of an unexpected exception).

The custom logging helper makes use of the Trace.Correlation and is particularly handy in the context of logging in WF. For example we have a state machine that invokes a series of sequential workflows. At each of these invoke activities we log the start (using StartLogicalOperation) and then at the end we stop the logical operation with a gereric return event handler.

This has proven useful a few times when attempting to debug failures in complex business sequences as it allows us to determine things like If/Else branch decisions etc. more quickly based on the activity execution sequence.

**What log outputs do you use?**

We use text files and XML files. Text files are configured through the app block but we've got XML outputs as well from our WF service. This enables us to capture the runtime events (persistence etc.) as well as generic business type exceptions. The text files are rolling logs that are rolled by day and size (I believe total size of 1MB is a rollover point).

**What tools to you use for viewing the logs?**

We are using Notepad and WCF Service Trace Viewer depending on which output group we're looking at. The WCF Service Trace Viewer is really really handy if you've got your output setup correctly and can make reading the output much simpler. That said, if I know roughly where the error is anyway - just reading a well annotated text file is good as well.

The logs are sent to a single directory which is then split into sub-dirs based on the source service. The root dir is exposed via a website which has it's access controlled by a support user group. This allows us to take a look at production logs without having to put in requests and go through lengthy red tape processes for production data.

Answer (score 6):

As the authors of the tool, we of course use [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/) for logging and tracing .NET applications. We usually use the named pipe protocol for live logging and (encrypted) binary log files for end-user logs. We use the SmartInspect Console as the viewer and monitoring tool.

There are actually quite a few logging frameworks and tools for .NET out there. There's an overview and comparison of the different tools on [DotNetLogging.com](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/).

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of great recommendations in the answers.

A general best practice is to consider who will be reading the log. In my case it will be an administrator at the client site. So I log messages that gives them something they can act on. For Example, "Unable to initialize application. This is usually caused by ......"

Answer (score 1):

We use log4net on our web applications.

It's ability to customize logging at run-time by changing the XML configuration file is very handy when an application is malfunctioning at run-time and you need to see more information.

It also allows you to target specific classes or attributes to log under.  This is very handy when you have an idea where the error is occurring.  A classic example is NHibernate where you want to see just the SQL going to the database.

Edit:

We write all events to a database and the Trace system.  The event log we use for errors or exceptions.  We log most events to a database so that we can create custom reports and let the users view the log if they want to right from the application.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you use it? Do you log to a file or the event log? Is it a rolling log file? What do you do to secure it or back it up? I'm interested in real-life use.

Answer (score 1):

As far as aspect oriented logging is concerned I was recommended PostSharp on another SO question -

[Aspect Oriented Logging with Unity\T4\anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633249/aspect-oriented-logging-with-unity-t4-anything-else)

The link provided in the answer is worth visiting if you are evaluating logging frameworks.