# Logging in .NET

Tags: asp.net, logging

I'm working on a new ASP.NET application and I'm interested in using a recommended approach for logging. My question to the community is, what logging framework do you like to use on your ASP.NET projects? What are the pros / cons? There are so many and they seem to change all the time that I'm just not sure which road to go down.

Thank you

Comment: mark this as community wiki... this question has been asked many times so you might want to make sure you are asking it in a new way.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/576185/64096

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)**

I've used Log4Net on a number of large projects, and it's always been reliable (and seems to be the majority of what my clients have been using already).

Answer (score 4):

*"ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment. "*

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've used at least 4 different logging frameworks, including the popular one mentioned by others. Personally, I would never use that framework if it were up to me--for lots of reasons.

My personal favorite is the object guy's logging framework found [here](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog). The only drawback is that it isn't free anymore. But it's practically free--and well-worth the time you'll save compared to trying to figure out some other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) as well. It works very well and outputs to a multiple interfaces like text files, telnet, DB etc. I've found it to be easy to use and configure.

Answer (score -1):

May be following two library, you could consider,

[ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/elmah/)

[AnLogger](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/AnLogger.aspx)

:)

Comment: this is a great example of low quality answer. The moment those links die, this answer is totally useless.